# How to set the selected state of Select2 component in React?

Tags: reactjs, jquery-select2

I have a React application that includes the npm package:

```
import Select2 from 'react-select2-wrapper';
```

My Select2 component looks like this:

```
<Select2
    options={{
        minimumResultsForSearch: Infinity
    }}
    data={[
        { text: '...', id: "" },
        { text: 'Edit', id: "edit" },
        { text: 'Duplicate', id: "duplicate" }
    ]}
    onChange={this.executeSelectedOption.bind(this)}
 />
```

I want to click a button and have it change the selected value of the Select2 component - how do I do this?

Comment: Yup, nothing obvious there.

Comment: Why react-select2-wrapper and not react-select2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`react-select2-wrapper`](https://github.com/rkit/react-select2-wrapper) has [`value`](https://github.com/rkit/react-select2-wrapper#value) attribute

```
var Select = React.createClass({
  getInitialState() {
    return { value: null }
  },

  handleClick(value) {
    this.setState({ value });
  },

  executeSelectedOption() {},

  render() {
    return <div>
      <p>
        <button onClick={ this.handleClick.bind(this, '') }>Select Empty</button>  
        <button onClick={ this.handleClick.bind(this, 'edit') }>Select Edit</button>
        <button onClick={ this.handleClick.bind(this, 'duplicate') }>Select Duplicate</button>
      </p>

      <Select2
        value={ this.state.value }

        options={{
          minimumResultsForSearch: Infinity
        }}

        data={[
          { text: '...', id: "" },
          { text: 'Edit', id: "edit" },
          { text: 'Duplicate', id: "duplicate" }
        ]}
        onChange={this.executeSelectedOption.bind(this)}
       />
    </div>
  }
});
```

[`Example`](http://www.webpackbin.com/4Jco4eJ_b)